# Как определить в какую из область на карте входит точка с известными координатами?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как определить в какую из область на карте входит точка с известными координатами?

```
function GoTargetZone(coordin1, coordin2){
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    [coordin1,coordin2],{id: nomerID
                },{});
                    myMap.geoObjects.add[nomerID];
       result.searchContaining(myPlacemark);
      }
```

[Или "песочница"](https://plnkr.co/edit/4lQqXwWGjlfFPBwP?preview)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ваши метки в [Выборку геообъектов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geoquery.html), после чего методом [searchInside](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__searchInside) определите объекты, которые попадают внутрь фигуры с указанной геометрией. Примеры есть в песочнице API Яндекс.Карт: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle